# Toolkit not initialized Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I am getting the follow error when I run a JavaFx application as "Run" only. Debug works fine...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Goose.Program.<clinit>(Program.java:26)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:512)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:87)
    ... 4 more
```

I have read that you should subclass Application but I am already doing that so I am not sure why it doesn't work... It works fine if I debug but as soon as I try to run the application instead of debugging it, it throws that error message. Which is a little crazy.... Anyone have any idea what the heck is going on? Here is the code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Program extends Application{
    TextField input;
    GameServer gm;
    Player p = new Player();

    /**
     * Just starts our GameServer
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        p.setState(Player.States.Ready);
        p.setAccess(Player.AccessStatus.GameMaster);
        input = new TextField();
        input.setPrefWidth(500);
        input.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
                textArea.appendText("Command: " + input.getText() + "\n");
                handleEvent(input);
                input.setText("");
            }
        });

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.add(input, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        gridPane.add(textArea, 0,2, 2, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 530, 250);
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(540);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(280);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(540);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(280);
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Server");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(we -> {
            try {
                textArea.appendText("Shutting down server...");
                if(gm.gameworld.getRunning()) {
                    gm.gameworld.setRunning(false);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        run();
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            GameServer gameServer = new GameServer();
            this.gm = gameServer;
            gameServer.start();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void handleEvent(TextField textField){
        try {
            String eventKey = textField.getText().trim();
            Event e = gm.gameworld.getEventHandler().stringToEvent.get(eventKey);
            if(e != null) {
                e.setPlayer(p);
                e.ready(gm.gameworld);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in the constructor for `Player`?

Comment: Nothing, blank constructor. Also removed All object references except JavaFx references and still same issue.... :(. But that debug works perfectly lol...... Such a weird issue.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the public static final TextArea textArea = new TextArea(); Are you not allowed to have a static final variable in the class? I removed the static and it works fine....... Bah..... What on earth?

Comment: @James_D is there something that I do not know about with javafx? lol. Not sure what I am missing and why I cant have a static.

Comment: Sorry: hit enter before I meant to: entire comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. That will attempt to create the text field before launch() is invoked. `launch()` starts the FX toolkit - so you're trying to create a FX control before the FX toolkit starts.

Comment: You can have a static control (if you really want: why though??), just not in the application class (even more: why?).

Comment: True, I just had it there because it was a copy and paste. And it didn't break anything in debug :P. So thanks for explaining! If you post the answer I will accept it :). Thanks!

Comment: I'll convert to an answer when I am back at my computer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `'public void init() throws Exception'` method in Application class whose documentation says:

"The application initialization method. This method is called immediately after the Application class is loaded and constructed. An application may **override** this method to perform initialization prior to the actual starting of the application". "NOTE: This method is not called on the **JavaFX** Application Thread. An application must not construct a Scene or a Stage in this method. An application may construct other JavaFX objects in this method."

So, I suppose that you should move: `p = new Player();` and
`textArea = new TextArea();` to it.